# Escape unescaped characters in XML with Python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, lxml, special-characters

I need to escape special characters in an invalid XML file which is about 5000 lines long. Here's an example of the XML that I have to deal with:

```
<root>
 <element>
  <name>name & surname</name>
  <mail>name@name.org</mail>
 </element>
</root>
```

Here the problem is the character "&" in the name. How would you escape special characters like this with a Python library? I didn't find a way to do it with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't care about invalid characters in the xml you could use XML parser's `recover` option  (see [Parsing broken XML with lxml.etree.iterparse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2352840/4279)):

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True) # recover from bad characters.
root = etree.fromstring(broken_xml, parser=parser)
print etree.tostring(root)
```

#### Output

```
<root>
<element>
<name>name  surname</name>
<mail>name@name.org</mail>
</element>
</root>
```

Comment: finally i used the parse method from lxml.html.soupparser : it can parse my ugly xml without crying :)  Thanks for your answer

Comment: This answer, while useful, won't escape the unescaped characters. It will apparently simply drop them.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably just wanting to do some simple regexp-ery on the HTML before throwing it into BeautifulSoup.

Even simpler, if there aren't any SGML entities (`&...;`) in the code, `html=html.replace('&','&amp;')` will do the trick.

Otherwise, try this:

```
x ="<html><h1>Fish & Chips & Gravy</h1><p>Fish &amp; Chips &#x0026; Gravy</p>"
import re
q=re.sub(r'&([^a-zA-Z#])',r'&amp;\1',x)
print q
```

Essentially the regex looks for `&` not followed by alpha-numeric or # characters. It won't deal with ampersands at the end of lines, but that's probably fixable.

Answer (score 0):

This answer provides XML sanitizer functions, although they don't escape the unescaped characters, but simply drop them instead.

## Using bs4 with lxml

**The question wondered how to do it with Beautiful Soup.** Here is a function which will sanitize a small XML `bytes` object with it. It was tested with the package requirements `beautifulsoup4==4.8.0` and `lxml==4.4.0`. Note that `lxml` is required here by `bs4`.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree

import bs4


def sanitize_xml(content: bytes) -> bytes:
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57450722/
    try:
        xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(content)
    except xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError:
        return bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, features='lxml-xml').encode()
    return content  # already valid XML
```

## Using only lxml

Obviously there is not much of a point in using both `bs4` and `lxml` when this can be done with `lxml` alone. This `lxml==4.4.0` using sanitizer function is essentially derived from the [answer by jfs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4997458/).

```py
import lxml.etree


def sanitize_xml(content: bytes) -> bytes:
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57450722/
    try:
        lxml.etree.fromstring(content)
    except lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError:
        root = lxml.etree.fromstring(content, parser=lxml.etree.XMLParser(recover=True))
        return lxml.etree.tostring(root)
    return content  # already valid XML
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<name>name & surname</name>
```

is not well-formed XML. It should be:

```
<name>name &amp; surname</name>
```

All conformant XML tools should create this - you normally do not have to worry. If you create a string with the '&' character then an XML tool will output the escaped version. If you create the string by hand it is your responsibility to make sure it is escaped. If you use an XML editor it should escape it for you.

If the file has been given you by someone else, send it back and tell them it is not well-formed. If they no longer exist you will have to use a plain text editor. That's fragile and messy but there is no other way. If the file has ampersands elsewhere that are used for escaping then the file is garbage.

See a 10-year-old post [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/01/31/qanda.html) and a later one [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/02/26/qa.html).

Comment: the xml is generated by a novell tool called **metamig** :  it exports the trustees from a **nss server**: there are folders with the & character so i have to escape all thoses ones to parse correctly the file

Comment: Assuning you have quoted it correctly it's PSEUDO-xml. I don't know this tool but if you have reported it correctly it should never have got out. It's just WRONG. And if you pay money for it, demand your money back.

Comment: Thank you peter, I didn't know the '&' should be escaped in a correct XML file. You saved me a research on why Python ElementTree didn't show the '&' character