# XML document can't be parsed due to strange characters

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I'm using Python 3 to retrieve data from an API but I have problems parsing some XML documents from retrieved strings.

I have identified the specific string which cause this problem:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree

bad_string = '<tag>Sample &#x91;cp 99-3a&#x92</tag>'
ElementTree.fromstring(bad_string)
```

This is the returned error which stops the script:

```py
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 31
```

I tried to solve it using some solutions like the one included below with the same result as before

```py
ElementTree.fromstring('<tag>Sample &#x91;cp 99-3a&#x92</tag>'.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

How can I clean this string without applying one specific regular expression to face other similar strings?

**Edit:** Now that @b_c and @mzjn explain that my problem are unescaped characters I find one possible solution ([Escape unescaped characters in XML with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972210/escape-unescaped-characters-in-xml-with-python))

```py
ElementTree.fromstring('<tag>&amp;Sample &#x91;cp 99-3a&#x92</tag>', parser = etree.XMLParser(recover = True))
```

Comment: `&#x92` is the problem. If it had a semicolon at the end (`&#x92;`) it would be a correct numerical character reference. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_reference_overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string contains HTML-Entities (whether it's XML or HTML) and needs to be un-escaped. The `&#x91;` and `&#x92` correlate to `‘` and `’`, respectively.

If you [use `html.unescape`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087433/4739755), you'll see the cleaned up text:

```
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape('<tag>Sample &#x91;cp 99-3a&#x92</tag>')
'<tag>Sample ‘cp 99-3a’</tag>'
```

**Edit**: @mzjn pointed out that you can also fix the string by adding a missing semicolon to the 2nd Entity:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tag = ET.fromstring('<tag>Sample &#x91;cp 99-3a&#x92;</tag>')
>>> tag.text
'Sample \x91cp 99-3a\x92'
```

But, you'll see that there's still `\x91` and `\x92` characters (and requires that you can control the string's content). These are the [MS CP1252 encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23092402/4739755) for left-and-right single quotation marks. Using the `html.unescape` method above will still give you the cleaned up text.

**Comment Follow-up**

In your comment, you added the additional wrinkle of your string containing *other* valid XML escape sequences (such as `&amp;`), which `html.unescape` will happily clean. Unfortunately, as you saw, that ends up taking you back to square one, as you now have have an `&` that *should* be escaped, but isn't (`ElementTree` would un-escape it for you).

```
>>> import html
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> cleaned = html.unescape('<tag>&amp;Sample &#x91;cp 99-3a&#x92</tag>')
>>> print(cleaned)
<tag>&Sample ‘cp 99-3a’</tag>
>>> ET.fromstring(cleaned)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 12
```

Some other options you have are to try using [`soupparser`](https://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) from `lxml.html`, which is much better at handling problematic HTML/XML:

```
>>> from lxml.html import soupparser
>>> soupparser.fromstring('<tag>&amp;Sample &#x91;cp 99-3 a&#x92;</tag>').text_content()
'&Sample ‘cp 99-3 a’'
```

Or depending on what your needs are, you might just be better off doing a string/regex replace before parsing it to remove the annoying cp1252 characters:

```
>>> import re
# Matches "&#x91" or "&#x92", with or without trailing semicolon
>>> node = ET.fromstring(re.sub(r'&#x9[1-2];?', "'", '<tag>&amp;Sample &#x91;cp 99-3 a&#x92;</tag>'))
>>> node.text
"&Sample 'cp 99-3 a'"
```

Comment: The semicolon is irrelevant, at least for `html.unescape` apparently. And yes, they _are_ [HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Comment: It is misleading to say "it's HTML with HTML-Entities". `bad_string` in the question would be well-formed XML if there was a semicolon after `&#x92`.

Comment: A lot of thanks @b_c and @mzjn, both solutions are valid but now I have another problem with `&amp;`. When I run for instance `ElementTree.fromstring(html.unescape('<tag>&amp;Sample &#x91;cp 99-3a&#x92</tag>'))` I have the same problem as before.

Comment: Updated with some additional options based on that :)

Comment: Awesome! This is the solution that I was looking for, thanks!