# Parsing broken XML with numbers as tag names

Tags: python, regex, xml, string, xml-parsing

I have lots of xml files that have keys that are in digit format i.e `<12345>Golly</12345>`

When parsing using `ElementTree` I get an error `not well-formed (invalid token)`. I am assuming this because the keys are in digit format and not words. When I try to change/replace the keys into string by adding double quotes using regex

```
xmlstr = re.sub('<([\d]+)>','<"' + str(re.search('<([\d]+)>', xmlstr).group(1))+ '">',xmlstr)
xmlstr = re.sub('</([\d]+)>','</"' + str(re.search('</([\d]+)>', xmlstr).group(1))+ '">',xmlstr)
```

All other keys are replace using the first found key.(all keys end up being the same. whereas the keys themselves in the original file are unique in each document.) I guess the files were converted from json to xml directly. The keys should represent id number and the values are the names associated with the id number

I was wondering if there is a way to work with digits as keys, or if there is a way I can replace the keys one by one and not replacing all matches with one found string. 
`.group(1)` returns the first occurrence which causes the problem.
Please Help.

Comment: This is not how to use `re.sub()`. The second argument should be a reference into the regexp, e.g. `re.sub(r"<(\d+)>", "<prefix\1>", xmlstr)`

Comment: i can only do  that way if and only if i know what am trying to replace... but i dont(the xml files are more are about 2500, one line files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to have both the numeric tag name and the content captured in different saving groups and then reference them in the replacement string:

```
In [2]: data = "<content><12345>Golly</12345><67890>Jelly</67890></content>"

In [3]: re.sub(r"<(\d+)>(.*?)</\d+>", r'<item id="\1">\2</item>', data)
Out[3]: '<content><item id="12345">Golly</item><item id="67890">Jelly</item></content>'
```

Though, it is difficult to come up with something 100% reliable without having access to the possible variations of the input XML data. For instance, I am not sure if this expression going to handle nested numerical tags nicely.

You may also want to explore possibilities to parse the document in [`lxml`'s "recovery" mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2352840/771848).

---

Another possible tool that may help to deal with this situation is `BeautifulSoup` - you may try the non-traditional approach - parse the XML data with a *lenient* `html5lib` parser:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: data = "<content><12345>Golly</12345><67890>Jelly</67890></content>"

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")
In [3]: print(soup.prettify())
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <content>
   &lt;12345&gt;Golly
   <!--12345-->
   &lt;67890&gt;Jelly
   <!--67890-->
  </content>
 </body>
</html>
```

It is not the desired output, of course, but may be something you can work with and extract the keys and words.

Comment: i can then scrape as an html file, or convert it back to a json string... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**lxml** package will make your life easier than struggling with regex.

Take a look at the [documentation page](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html).

> pip install lxml

```
file_path = 'your/xml/file.xml'
parser_obj = lxml.etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
lxml.etree.parse(file_path, parser=parser_obj)
```

Comment: It's not going to handle a case like `<content><12345>Golly</12345><67890>Jelly</67890></content>` as is..`67890` would be lost altogether.

Comment: ahh... got you.